# Run a script before Command Prompt stops

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, discord.js, command-prompt

I have a Discord Bot that edits a message every second. So if the bot goes off, the message will display the last edit.

I would like to, before closing the Node JS process (using Ctrl + C, closing the Command Prompt or any type of closing the process), edit the message to say something like: "The bot is off".

Example:

```
// something using discord.js
bot.on("close", myFunction);

// or in node, like in browser 'window.onbeforeunload'
node.beforecloseprocess = myFunction;
```

If theres a way with discord.js, that would be cool and resolve my problem, but if there a way of using Node Js it self or something in the Command Prompt would be better for future projects aside discord.js.

Comment: See [node-cleanup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cleanup) for example.

Comment: thanks, its just what i need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the discord.js event 'close' and call a function that would change the message to 'The bot is off'.

also:

```js
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  console.log("Closing")
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working but the process is not stoping anymore

Comment: oh, i just added process.kill and its now stopping

Comment: thanks, this is better than node-cleanup becouse i dont neet to use any new require

Comment: np. Also, `process.exit()` if you don't want to mess with pid.

Comment: Be sure to note that this is just one of many possible exit reasons.

Comment: @0x464e is there a way to match all of the possible exit reasons?

Comment: @LuísHNrique I'm not qualified to properly answer this, but maybe using the `node-cleanup` package, which I suggested earlier, would be a good way. It covers a lot, not sure if *every possible* exit reason, maybe, maybe not.